# How to use regexp on file, line by line, in Python

Tags: python, regex

Here is my regexp: `f\(\s*([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,]+)\s*\)`

I'd have to apply this on a file, line by line. The line by line is OK, simple reading from file, and a loop. But how do I apply the regexp to the lines?

Thanks for all the help, and sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 35):

The following expression returns a list; every entry of that list contains all matches of your regexp in the respective line.

```
>>> import re
>>> [re.findall(r'f\(\s*([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,]+)\s*\)',line) 
            for line in open('file.txt')]
```

Comment: Even if your answer is very close to the one from Cédric Julien, I've voted yours because of the list comprehension and the explanation

Answer (score 19):

You can try something like this :

```
import re
regex = re.compile("f\(\s*([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,]+)\s*\)")
with open("my_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = regex.search(line)
```

Comment: Make some time measurement before precompile the pattern.

Answer (score 12):

```
import re
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.search('f\(\s*([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,]+)\s*\)', line)
```

Note that Python automatically compiles and caches the regex, so a separate compile step is not required in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do

```
import re
[line for line in open('file.txt') if re.match(r'f\(\s*([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,]+)\s*\)',line)]
```

Answer (score 3):

use `import re`, then `re.compile()` with your pattern as an argument, and use the resulting object's `match` attribute on each line.  something like this..

```
import re 
pat = re.compile(r'f\(\s*([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,]+)\s*\)')
for line in file:
  # use pat.match, pat.search .. etc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in file:
   line = re
           .match("f\(\s*([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,]+)\s*\)",line)
           .group(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used this aproach:

```
import re
#Define the search term:
pattern = r"f\(\s*([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,]+)\s*\)" #pattern must be enclosed in quotes

#Create an empty list:
data = []

#then

for line in open(r'file.txt'):
    if line !='':  #<-- To make sure the whole file is read
        word = re.findall(pattFinder1, line)
        data.append(str(word))
```