# regex using python language

Tags: python, regex, email

I have a txt file with various email addresses and other lines that are not valid emails, I am trying to print only the valid email addresses, when I use the code below, nothing is printed.
This is the content of the txt file:

```
blbabal@gmail.com   
hey@gmail.com

lalalalal
```

In this case, only both the email addresses should be printed

```
 import re

    my_file = open('emails.txt', 'r+')
```

Comment: Add `re.M` flag, `re.findall(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$", my_file.read(), re.M)`

Comment: It is very similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6186938/4636715 except you specifically look for email addresses. But as your point is not the regex you've built, it can be considered as a dupe.

Comment: @vahdet It is not similar to that question. Here, the whole line must match a pattern.

Comment: nothing is printed because the `for` loop is iterating over the file, which has already seeked to the end with `.read()`. why aren't you iterating over `items`  instead?

Comment: You are looking for matches, storing them in `items` and in the very next line your are overwriting `items`.

Answer (score 1):

You may fix your code if you add `re.M` flag:

```
re.findall(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$", my_file.read(), re.M)
```

Since you read in the whole file with `my_file.read()`, the `^` and `$` should match start/end of the *line*, not *string*, and the `re.M` flag does that.

Also, you may read the file line by line and only get those lines that fully match your pattern:

```
items = []
email_rx = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$")
with open('emails.txt', 'r+') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        if email_rx.match(line):
            items.append(line)
```

Note that only `$` anchor is necessary as `re.match` only [anchors matches at the start of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180993/3832970).

Note that you may have CRLF endings, then, you might either `rstrip` each line before testing against regex and appending to `items`,  or add `\s*` pattern at the end before `$` anchor.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
my_file = open('emails.txt', 'r+')
items = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", my_file.read())
for items in items:
    print(items)
```

Two problems

1. for item in items instead of file
2. remove ^ and $ from your pattern.

Comment: If you remove the anchors, the email like substrings that do not equal the whole line will get extracted, too. OP used the anchors for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

This should print all emails in the file

```
import re
reg = '[A-Za-z0-9.]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+[.][a-z]+'
with open('email.txt', 'r') as f1:
    for email in f1:
        if(len(re.findall(reg,email))!=0):
            print(email)
```

And this should get only whole line emails -

```
import re
reg = '[A-Za-z0-9.]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+[.][a-z]+'
with open('email.txt', 'r') as f1:
    for email in f1:
        if(len(re.findall(reg,email))):
            if(len(re.findall(reg,email)[0])==len((email.replace("\n","")))):
                print(email)
```

Comment: OP only wants those emails that are equal to whole lines.

Comment: Check the second part of code that willget the lines with only whole email in it.

Comment: There is a more straight-forward approach, see my answer.